# trigger property of bootstrap vue popover doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, popover, bootstrap-vue

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="space in items">
    <span
        class="p-absolute space-menu"
        :id="'manage-popover-' + space.id"
    >
        <i
            class="flaticon-more-1 lighter-font"
        ></i>
    </span>
    <b-popover
        :target="
            'manage-popover-' + space.id
        "
        triggers="focus"
        placement="auto"
    >
        <b-row
            align-v="center"
            class="py-2 px-3 hoverable-popover"
            v-b-modal.delete-space-modal
        >
            <b-col cols="12 pointer-class">
                <i
                    class="flaticon-delete"
                ></i>
                <span class="lighter-font">
                    Delete
                </span>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-popover>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to use bootstrap-vue popover but when I use the triggers property of focus or blur the popover does not show anything.
Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Please share the code sample that you tried.

Comment: here you are. @YashMaheshwari

Comment: I think don't pass target and id as v-bind. Simply use `target="'manage-popover-' + space.id"` and `id="'manage-popover-' + space.id"` instead of `:id`

Comment: No it does not work for me that way.

Comment: i have same issue on vuexy ( vue JS 2 ) it doesnt work